# Output Stops and Debug doesn't work

Tags: javascript, debugging

Working on a "Ultimate Colour Converter" just as something to do and I can get can the colour models to convert to HSL but for some reason when I convert HSL back, the whole thing breaks. I can't even submit it again.

I have also added a bunch of debug lines in the code where it broke but nothing gets reported to console.

My current project can be found here: http://codepen.io/spedwards/pen/ikJxH or http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/se5yU/

As the code is really long, I'll refrain from posting the whole thing but just a segment of it.

```
 else if (type == 'hsl') {
    hsl = type;console.debug(hsl = type);

    /* START RGB */
    c = type.slice(4).split(',');console.debug('Removed first 4 chars');
    c[2] = c[2].substring(0, c[2].length - 1);console.debug('Removed last bracket');
    c = hslToRgb(c[0],c[1],c[2]);console.debug('Convert to RGB');

    rgb = 'rgb(' + c.join() + ')';console.debug('Sets RGB');
    /* END RGB */
    /* START RGBA */
    rgba = (rgb.substring(0, rgb.length - 1) + ',1)').splice(3,0,'a');console.debug('Sets RGBA');
    /* END RGBA */
    /* START HEX */
    hex = '#';console.debug('Starts hex');
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
      c[i] = +c[i];console.debug('Coerces to number: ' + i);
      hex += (c[i] < 16 ? "0" : "") + c[i].toString(16).toUpperCase();console.debug('Sets hex part: ' + i);
    }
    /* END HEX */
  }



function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
}
```

I should note, `type` comes in as `hsl(0,0,1)` or whatever is being input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what my problem was. I had forgotten to change `type == 'hsl'` to `colourType == 'hsl'`.

All works now.